# How to Solidify a mesh so I can use it´s measurements to build the object it in real life?

Tags: modeling, mesh, modifiers

I built a geometric sculpture in blender that I want to build in real life.

So I need its exact measurements and that the walls of my object do not overlap. In the reference image I use a cube as an example. The cube measures 200 x 200 cm. Assuming that my wall is 20 cm thick, I need my mesh not to overlap, and its measurements. Is there a tool or a way to do it? Not even sure if thickness modifier is the right way to do it.

In the third image you can see my sculpture, the 4 pieces i need (with the thick walls (faces) and the two examples of what I need using cubes). As you can see, the cube walls do not overlap because the wall ends just where the other one starts. Sorry for my bad english.

[image: Reference of wall thickness]

[image: Cube reference as example]

See the reference 2 as an example

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I got it right. Do you want to measure the object to ensure that it is not over the limit? (for example, to ensure that an object is not going through the wall)

In this scenario, you can measure the bounding box of the object and compare whether it is exceeding the limits. See this example:
[image]
[in this example, the Monkey needs to fit inside the box, this box have 0.8cm and the Monkey needs to be smaller than that. See the "Dimensions", this shows the measurements of the bounding box, so with these values, you can be sure that the Monkey is smaller or not]

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. It is not exactly what I was looking for, but your answer has resolved some doubts. What I'm looking for is to assemble this piece in wood, but for that I need to know the thickness of the walls, so i can build its structure.

My model only has the measurements like the cube below, because their faces are flat, but I need the measurements to build the sculpture like the cube above (with individual thick walls).

I edited my question. In the image from left to right: my sculpture, the 8 pieces I need to build, and the two example cubes.

Comment: I don't understand very well. Your main problem is that you can't measure certain parts of your object? (for example: pick one point and another point and get the distance between them? like this measure addon that I'm using: https://i.stack.imgur.com/eAyZ3.gif )